# sudo gem install cocoapods --pre error

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire

today I going to use swift 3.0, so I want to use cocoapods to install Alamofire 4.0, but terminal note that require cocoapods 1.1.0, my pods is 1.0.1, so I use sudo gem install cocoapods --pre to update, But get error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error says is that you can't write to: `/usr/bin`. Try this and see if it makes any difference:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre
```